# How to translate/redraw a triangle geometry using a set of new points in 3D

Tags: .net, wpf

I am creating a triangle as follows:

```
meshBuilder.AddTriangle(new Point3D(x, y, z));
var mesh = meshBuilder.ToMesh(true);

myTrianglegeometry = new GeometryModel3D();
myTrianglegeometry.Material = greenMaterial;
myTrianglegeometry.BackMaterial = yellowMaterial;
myTrianglegeometry.Geometry = mesh;
modelGroup.Children.Add(myTrianglegeometry);

myModelVisual3D = new ModelVisual3D();
myModelVisual3D.Content = modelGroup;
```

Now my program is updating the values for x, y, and z. So, I am calling the above code for each update of x, y, z which creates a new triangle every-time a set of new x,y,z are available. This works but computationally very intensive and causes the UI response very slow.

To avoid this, how should I re-draw/re-position "myTrianglegeometry" to the new values of x,y,z rather than creating new triangles? Is it possible to change the vertices of the "myTrianglegeometry"?

Please guide me in this regard.

Thanks.

Comment: Could anyone please guide me how to re-position a triangle shape to a new set of points? My program is updating the position of three points which I am using to draw a triangle. Now how to re-position the triangle to the new set of points?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use a view matrix to translate/rotate/scale. Why not do this?